# nftables: referencing a set from another table

Tags: nftables

With the following setup:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f
add table ip filter
add chain ip filter input { type filter hook input priority 0; }
add set   ip filter nat-group-1 { type ipv4_addr; }
add set   ip filter nat-group-2 { type ipv4_addr; }
add set   ip filter nat-group-3 { type ipv4_addr; }
add set   ip filter nat-group-4 { type ipv4_addr; }
add set   ip filter nat-group-5 { type ipv4_addr; }
add rule  ip filter input ip saddr @nat-group-1 tcp dport 22 drop
add table ip nat
add chain ip nat postrouting {type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept; }
add rule  ip nat postrouting ip saddr @nat-group-1 snat to 192.168.1.0/24 persistent
add rule  ip nat postrouting ip saddr @nat-group-2 snat to 192.168.2.0/24 persistent
```

I get the error message

```
Error: No such file or directory; did you mean set ‘nat-group-1’ in table ip ‘filter’?
```

I do not know how to reference a set from another table. Is this possible? Suspect one can get around this issue by duplicating the set in the two tables, but the error message makes me hopeful that there is some syntax that I'm not aware of.

I will be referencing the set in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Contrary for example with *iptables*' companion *ipset* which lives outside of *iptables* and thus doesn't have any scope limit by the way both interact, the scope of an *nftables* set is limited to the table where it's defined.

It's simply not possible to reference an other table from a table, so all objects in an other table can't be referenced, including sets defined in an other table.

### Solution

One should think differently when using *nftables* than from using *iptables*: tables roles are not fixed.

Whenever possible, the same table should be used from different hook types, if they are to work together.

For OP's case, `chain ip filter input` and `chain ip nat postrouting` can just be put in the same table, because it's the same family (`ip`). So just rewrite the ruleset slightly. For example let's call the common table `multinat` and just rewrite mechanically (eg: `sed 's/ip filter/ip multinat/g;s/ip nat/ip multinat/g'`. Adding again an existing table is not an error but just a no-op) everything into this table:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f
add table ip multinat
add chain ip multinat input { type filter hook input priority 0; }
add set   ip multinat nat-group-1 { type ipv4_addr; }
add set   ip multinat nat-group-2 { type ipv4_addr; }
add set   ip multinat nat-group-3 { type ipv4_addr; }
add set   ip multinat nat-group-4 { type ipv4_addr; }
add set   ip multinat nat-group-5 { type ipv4_addr; }
add rule  ip multinat input ip saddr @nat-group-1 tcp dport 22 drop
add table ip multinat
add chain ip multinat postrouting {type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept; }
add rule  ip multinat postrouting ip saddr @nat-group-1 snat to 192.168.1.0/24 persistent
add rule  ip multinat postrouting ip saddr @nat-group-2 snat to 192.168.2.0/24 persistent
```

Now the *set* in the table can be access from both chains, because they are all in the same table. Contrary to *iptables*, it doesn't matter that the chains in the table have a different hook types.

### Other cases

Now the same change can't be applied between tables of different families (`netdev`, `bridge`, `arp`, `ip` `ip6`, `inet`).

Between `ip`, `ip6` and `inet` (which is the combination of IPv4 and IPv6) the solution is still simple: put everything into an `inet` family table and adapt a few rules where one has to disambiguate  between `ip` and `ip6`.

For the other cases, one other method is to mark packets or flows in the first happening chain where it can make a decision so the later happening chain can retrieve the mark without having to check again.

If none of this can be done, then I see no other way than duplicate the sets in multiple tables.